# Why doesn't a Business Data List web part work in a published page?

Tags: 2010, web-part, cumulative-update, custom-bdc

I have an existing publishing page with an XSL customized Business Data List web part (pulling from an SQL source).  When I do a search with the web part, the loading graphic shows like it's searching but never disappears.  If I check out the page it works fine. It's only when it's published that the external list breaks.

The only thing I can figure is that I just installed the Feb 2013 CU.  Could this be a glitch or added security with the new CU?  The XSL does add some JavaScript to the web part.

Comment: I'm on to the cause.  Found this in the ULS --  System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: The security validation for this page is invalid. Click Back in your Web browser, refresh the page, and try your operation again. -- Disabling page validation (not a permanent fix) causes it to work but why did it work before?

Comment: I found that I had loaded a .js file via a CEWP for that page.  Weird thing is that even if a CEWP is on the page with no content in it, the web part will not display the business data after publishing the page.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is to use the HTML form web part to load the script.  Since I only need the code to function after the page loads (and the business data web part has done its job), this works for me.  Thanks to Marc and Christophe - http://blog.pathtosharepoint.com/2010/10/27/about-scripts-web-parts-and-urban-myths/?utm_source=twitterfeed&utm_medium=twitter&utm_campaign=Path+to+SharePoint

I have to assume this is a glitch resulting from the Feb 2013 CU since it was working until then.  Of course upgrading to SP1, skipping the June 2011 CU and going straight to Feb 2013 may also have contributed.

Answer (score 0):

If you edit the web part, in the properties pane there is a AJAX Options section. Disable the first option and you would be good to go. You may explore these options further if you are interested.

Hope that helps.